# Oracle generic streaming filter function

Tags: oracle, function, streaming, transformation, pipeline

Let's say I have multiple **different** tables in my Oracle database. All with some common fields like STATUS, PREP_STATUS and CREATEDATE. Since I'm lazy I don't want to replicate the same code all over. I'd like to do something like:

`SELECT * FROM TABLE(my_filter(CURSOR(SELECT * FROM tableA/B/C/D)))`

where my_filter() is my own generic filter function. It receives a cursor, filter specific records, and then "forward" the record. Something like the following pseudo code.

```
FUNCTION my_filter(p_cur IN SYS_REFCURSOR)
    RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR PIPELINED
AS
    l_var SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    FOR l_var IN SELECT * FROM CURSOR(p_cur)
        WHERE (l_var.STATUS = 'ACTIVE')
        AND ...);
    LOOP
        PIPE ROW (l_var);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I've seen examples where they define Types, but I'm looking for a generic solution that works essentially for all tables that have these common attributes.

Any idea how to implement that?

thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: To make it more clear, could you post the original queries, that you are lazy to write...